# The name 'MethodName' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

In my localplayer class I have 4 properties that looks like this:

```
        public class LocalPlayer : Player
{
    #region METHODS

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[CSLocalPlayer m_iCrosshairIdx={1}, m_iShotsFired={2}, m_vecPunch={0}]\n{3}",
            VecPunch, CrosshairIdx, ShotsFired, base.ToString());
    }

    #endregion

    #region FIELDS
    public Vector3 VecViewOffset => ReadFieldProxy<Vector3>("CSLocalPlayer.m_vecViewOffset");
    public Vector3 VecPunch => ReadFieldProxy<Vector3>("CSLocalPlayer.m_vecPunch");
    public int ShotsFired => ReadFieldProxy<int>("CSLocalPlayer.m_iShotsFired");
    public int CrosshairIdx => ReadFieldProxy<int>("CSLocalPlayer.m_iCrosshairIdx");
    #endregion

    #region CONSTRUCTORS

    public LocalPlayer(int address) : base(address)
    {
        AddField<Vector3>("CSLocalPlayer.m_vecViewOffset", Offsets.NetVars.LocalPlayer.VecViewOffset);
        AddField<Vector3>("CSLocalPlayer.m_vecPunch", Offsets.NetVars.LocalPlayer.VecPunch);
        AddField<int>("CSLocalPlayer.m_iShotsFired", Offsets.NetVars.LocalPlayer.ShotsFired);
        AddField<int>("CSLocalPlayer.m_iCrosshairIdx", Offsets.NetVars.LocalPlayer.CrosshairIdx);
    }

    public LocalPlayer(Player player) : base(player)
    {
        CopyFieldsFrom(player);
        AddField<Vector3>("CSLocalPlayer.m_vecViewOffset", Offsets.NetVars.LocalPlayer.VecViewOffset);
        AddField<Vector3>("CSLocalPlayer.m_vecPunch", Offsets.NetVars.LocalPlayer.VecPunch);
        AddField<int>("CSLocalPlayer.m_iShotsFired", Offsets.NetVars.LocalPlayer.ShotsFired);
        AddField<int>("CSLocalPlayer.m_iCrosshairIdx", Offsets.NetVars.LocalPlayer.CrosshairIdx);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

They should use my ReadFieldProxy from my Entity Class that is here:

```
namespace SimpleCsgoApplication.CSGO
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     An abstract class meant for managing Entities
    ///     Utilizes a hashtable to manage reading data and cache data
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class Entity
    {
    #region METHODS

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[Entity Address={Address.ToString("X")}]";
    }

    #endregion

    #region PROPERTIES

    protected Hashtable Fields { get; }
    public int Address { get; protected set; }

    #endregion

    #region CONSTRUCTORS

    public Entity(int address)
    {
        Address = address;
        Fields = new Hashtable();
        SetupFields();
    }

    public Entity() : this(0)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region HELPERS

    protected void AddField<T>(string fieldName, int offset, T value = default(T)) where T : struct
    {
        Fields[fieldName] = new Field<T>(offset, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns the value of the given field if the field has read its value before
    ///     Makes the field read its value if it did not do so before
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="fieldName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T ReadFieldProxy<T>(string fieldName) where T : struct
    {
        var field = (Field<T>)Fields[fieldName];
        if (!field.ValueRead)
            field.ReadValue(Address);
        return field.Value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Copies the fields of one Entity to another one;
    ///     Used for copy-constructors
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="other"></param>
    protected void CopyFieldsFrom<T>(T other) where T : Entity
    {
        foreach (string key in other.Fields.Keys)
            Fields[key] = other.Fields[key];
    }

    protected virtual void SetupFields()
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

But for some reason I can't find ReadFieldProxy from my localplayer class? They are both in the same namespace, and my ReadFieldProxy is public, so why can't I use it?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. This code doesn't even look like it will compile. Show the containing classes and the relation between `Entity` and `localplayer`.

Comment: which revision of .Net are you using >

Comment: you need an object reference to your `Entity` class before you can access it's members.

Comment: @PleaseTeach that is irrelevant.

Comment: @CodeCaster If they want to reproduce this problem they would need a game called " Counter-Strike: Global Offensive " and know the current offsets etc. and providng all that information in this question I would write an essay

Comment: Well that's not our problem. From the code given we can't analyze the problem. You need to create an example that at least represents the issue, this code does not.

Comment: @CodeCaster not everyone is as experienced as you, so it does helps :)

Comment: The minimum that CodeCaster is asking for is for these methods to be shown in their relevant classes

Comment: Thanks for the update. What is the `field => expression` syntax, are you using C# 6? Where is the `Player` class, does it inherit `Entity`?

Comment: I'm using c# 6, correct. LocalPlayer Innherits Player, Player Inherits BaseEntity, inherits Entity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate your Entity class before you can use its methods, i.e., you need to use something like

```
Enitity ent = new Entity();
```

and then use its methods like this:-

```
public Vector3 VecViewOffset => ent.ReadFieldProxy<Vector3>("CSLocalPlayer.m_vecViewOffset");
```

If you do not want to instantiate the class, you have to declare it static

```
public static abstract class Entity {...}
```

and then use

```
public Vector3 VecViewOffset => Entity.ReadFieldProxy<Vector3>("CSLocalPlayer.m_vecViewOffset");
```